# Does CouchDB replication require an admin of the system or the database admin?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I setup some security on a database called *test*.

The user with the name "user_test" is not a system Admin. Therefore, he has the admin permissions and member permissions on the *test* database.

As stated :

> Creating design documents is restricted to admins, and if the replication is triggered without admin credentials, writing the design documents during replication will fail and be recorded as doc_write_failures. If you have admins, be sure to include the credentials in the replication request:

Since they are referring to the design docs, I was thinking about the database admin.

Therefore, when I try to setup a replication document in the _replicator database, the connection "hang" with the "user_text" credentials.

If I use my system admin, the replication get triggered instantly.

## So my question :

In the **target** or **source** property, do I need to put the system admin credential or the database admin credentials?

## Update

Setting up a replication using a system admin gets triggered automatically (good).

If I use a database admin, nothing occurs. Not even an error. Wich is kind of weird because it works on other pcs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you information, after testing and fixing some errors, I figured out that you can use non-system admin for replication.

Even tough, I had some problems with my replications that were having errors. I ended up clearing the corrupted documents in the _replicator and restarting each instance and everything got fixed.